# arraybounds exception & constructor values are not visible to doInBackground in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I am getting "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0" while executing background tasks. Please help.

```
 ArrayList<String> ilist ,rlist,glist,yearlist;
 public static final String FetchURL = "http://fxxxx.fxxx.com/fetchdesc.php";

 new fetchDescInBack(ilist,rlist,glist,yearlist).execute();


private class fetchDescInBack extends AsyncTask<ArrayList,String,String>
{
    private final ArrayList<String> ilist,rlist,glist,yearlist;
    URL url;

    Context context;


    public fetchDescInBack(ArrayList<String> ilist, ArrayList<String> rlist, ArrayList<String> glist, ArrayList<String> yearlist) {
        this.ilist = ilist;
        this.rlist = rlist;
        this.glist = glist;
        this.yearlist = yearlist;
        this.context=context;
        Log.e("Shiva", "" + ilist);
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(ArrayList... params) {
       ArrayList ilist = params[0];
       ArrayList rlist = params[1];
       ArrayList glist = params[2];
       ArrayList yearlist = params[3];
       try {
           url = new URL(FetchURL);
           HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

           InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
           InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
           BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

           StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
           String tempstring;

           while ((tempstring = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
               stringBuilder.append(tempstring);
               stringBuilder.append("\n");
           }

       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }


       return null;
    }
```

I am passing 4 list of values from another activity to this class under Asynctask. So I used constructor and passed the values to the Asynctask. But there is exception and values assigned in constructor are not able to fetch inside doInBackground task. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is correct. `ArrayList... params`, the former parameter of `doInBackground`, refers to the arguments you pass to `execute()` no to the constructor.

```
new fetchDescInBack(ilist,rlist,glist,yearlist).execute(ilist,rlist,glist,yearlist);
```

should fix it. To avoid confusion you should choose or to use the `constructor` to pass the values or using `params`

Comment: After the above changes there is no exception. As you said, i already using the constructor Please check my code.

Comment: In question which is above i added the code which used the constructor. So i asked the above declaration is what you mentioned?